# Set Datasource location on Crystal Reports 2008 report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Reports 2008 report with dynamic parameters (e.g Distribution point which are referring to a column `DP.distributionPoint`). When opening the report in my application (C#) I am setting the datasource at run time and report opens properly and on the `Enter Parameter Values` window for report shows available values for distribution point (`DP.distributionPoint`).

Code I am using to set datasource dynamically (note there is no subreport for this report, but report is referring to database tables and views from the database)

```
SetDataSource(ReportDocument report, string serverName, string databaseName)
{
    //  Set the connection for the main report.
    report.DataSourceConnections[0].SetConnection(serverName, databaseName, true);

    TableLogOnInfo tableLogonInfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
    ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
    connectionInfo.DatabaseName = databaseName;
    connectionInfo.ServerName = serverName;
    connectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = true;

    foreach (Table table in report.Database.Tables)
    {
        tableLogonInfo = table.LogOnInfo;
        tableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = connectionInfo;
        table.ApplyLogOnInfo(tableLogonInfo);

        table.Location = tableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName + ".dbo." +
                     table.Location.Substring(table.Location.LastIndexOf(".") + 1);
    }
}
```

I need to set datasource every time I open the report. My plan is to set datasource on the report and save the report with location information, so next time I need not to call set datasource.

But when I test the application without setdatasource, I can open the report but 
Available Values for Distribution point in ‘Enter Parameter Values’ window is not showing now.

Note:

1. I have checked the table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName and table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName for all the tables/views in the report it is same as the database I am connecting to.
2. If I set set table.Location I can view Available Values List.

Questions:

1. Why available values list not showing when I open the report without setdatasource function?
2. Is it possible to change/control the available values for FieldParameter programmatically in Crystal Reports 2008?